My 98 ford explorer ac:air won’t turn off unless I turn it off have no clue where to look
Could it be a blower motor or blender or something else?

Ac will turn off but the fan it self won’t leaving it running until I turn the car off

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The blower motor on some vehicles is a little strange, in that there is always power applied to it, then it is grounded through the fan resistor via the switch. If the resistor goes out, it can ground and cause it to continue to run, sometimes even with the ignition turned off. I don't know which vehicles this can happen on, but yours may be one of them.
